How may I round the pts from \ht?
\newbox\mybox{}
\setbox\mybox=\vtop{This is the content of the box} 
\the\ht\mybox\  This is the height of the box
\par
\the\mybox\ This is the number of the box\par
\box16
How do I get a rounded 6.94pt from 6.94444pt ?
\bye


Are eTeX extensions fine?

What's the overall aim here? As hinted at in comments on answers, TeX stores dimens in sp and does integer arithmetic, converting to floats at the last possible moment.

The following defines an unexpandable plain TeX macro called \round. It has the syntax \round{<places>}{<number-like>} and will round <number-like> to <places> decimal places. A negative <places> argument will round to the integer part (so \round{-1}{5.5} will result in 10).
It sets the token register \roundResult to the result of the rounding operation. Trailing units are contained unaltered. Your <number-like> should expand to anything with a leading integer part, then if after that is a dot there must be a decimal part (so \round{2}{3.} results in a low level TeX error).
\begingroup
\catcode`\@=11
\def\round#1{#1}
\round{%
\endgroup
\csname newcount\endcsname\round@int
\csname newcount\endcsname\round@dec
\csname newcount\endcsname\round@places
\csname newtoks\endcsname\round@trail
\csname newtoks\endcsname\roundResult
\def\round#1#2{%
  \round@places=#1\relax
  \afterassignment\round@afterint
  \round@int=#2\relax
}
\def\round@first#1#2\relax{#1}
\def\round@afterfi#1\fi{\fi#1}
\def\round@collect#1\relax{\roundResult={#1}}
\def\round@afterint#1{%
  \ifx.#1%
    \afterassignment\round@afterdec
    \round@dec=%
  \else
    \ifnum\round@places>0
      \round@places=0
    \fi
    \round@afterfi{\round@intloop#1}%
  \fi
}
\def\round@afterdec{%
  \ifnum\round@places>0
    \expandafter\round@loop
  \else
    \ifnum\round@places=0
      \ifnum\expandafter\round@first\the\round@dec\relax>4
        \advance\round@int1
      \fi
    \fi
    \expandafter\round@intloop
  \fi
}
\def\round@intloop{%
  \round@trail{}%
  \loop\ifnum\round@places<0
    \round@trail\expandafter{\the\round@trail0}%
    \ifnum\round@places=-1
      \advance\round@int5
    \fi
    \divide\round@int10
    \advance\round@places1
    \ifnum\round@int=0
      \round@trail{}%
      \round@places=0
    \fi
  \repeat
  \expandafter\round@collect\the\expandafter\round@int\the\round@trail
}
\def\round@loop{%
  \expandafter\round@count\the\round@dec\relax
  \loop\ifnum\round@places<0
    \ifnum\round@places=-1
      \advance\round@dec5
    \fi
    \divide\round@dec10
    \advance\round@places1
  \repeat
  \expandafter\round@collect
    \the\expandafter\round@int\expandafter.\the\round@dec
}
\def\round@count#1{%
  \ifx\relax#1%
  \else
    \advance\round@places-1
    \expandafter\round@count
  \fi
}
}

\newbox\mybox
\setbox\mybox=\vtop{This is the content of the box}
\the\ht\mybox\ This is the height of the box
\par
\round{2}{\the\ht\mybox}\the\roundResult\ This is the rounded height of the box
\par
\the\mybox\ This is the number of the box\par
\box16
How do I get a rounded 6.94pt from 6.94444pt ?
\bye


Really good, thank you.

This will be a part of my favourites. :-)

I can’t understand the \csname shenanigans. In the sense that they’re useless.

@egreg Which \csname-shenanigans? The ones at the top for \newcount et al.? Those are \outer in plain so \csname is necessary as they are in an argument.

@egreg they could've been avoided if I resetted the @-catcode at the end instead of grouping it and using argument tokenisation.

@Skillmon Which is the clearer thing to do in order to separate internal from external macros.

The separation of internal from external macros is usage of @ in their names, which is what the code above does. The scope is delimited by the brace. The alternative would've been a construct such as \expandafter\edef\csname round@restore@\endcsname{\csname@=\the\csname@\relax} and using that, but I just didn't feel like it. Anyway, in the code above the \csname aren't useless.

Maybe, you want this:
\newdimen\value

\value=6.94444pt

\the\value  % prints 6.94444pt

\let\ea=\expandafter
\ea\def \ea\readvalue \ea#\ea1\detokenize{pt}{#1}
\def\modifyvalue #1.#2#3#4\end{#1.#2#3}

\value=\ea\modifyvalue\expanded{\ea\readvalue\the\value}{}{}\end pt

\the\value  % prints 6.94pt

\bye

This code does truncating. If you want rounding, do \advance\value by 0.005pt before truncating.

doesn't this truncate rather than round? though given the OP's self-answer, I'm no longer sure I have any idea what the question is.

Yes, this is truncating. And only very fragile truncating because if we set something in decimal representation to the dimen value in pt, then it is re-interpreted to multiples of sp and \the\value can print something different than what was set. This is reason that "Maybe" OP wants this. I am not sure.

Auxiliary macros ...
\newbox\mybox{}
\setbox\mybox=\vtop{This is the content of the box}
\the\ht\mybox\  This is the height of the box
\par
\the\mybox\ This is the number of the box\par
\box16
How do I get a rounded 6.94pt from 6.94444pt?
\newcount\mycount
\def\myrndaux#1.#2#3#4#5\nil{%
  \ifnum #4>4
    \mycount=#3
    \ifnum\mycount<9
      \advance\mycount by 1
      #1.#2\the\mycount pt%
    \else
      \mycount=#2
      \ifnum\mycount<9
        \advance\mycount by 1
        #1.\the\mycount 0pt%
      \else
        \mycount=#1
        \advance\mycount by 1
        \the\mycount .00pt%
      \fi
    \fi
  \else
    #1.#2#3pt%
  \fi
}%
\def\mydept#1pt{#1}%
\def\myinteger#1.#2\nil{#1}%
\def\mydecimal#1.#2\nil{#2}%
\def\myrnd#1{%
  \edef\tmpa{\expandafter\mydept#1}%
  \edef\tmpb{\expandafter\myinteger\tmpa.0\nil
  .\expandafter\mydecimal\tmpa.0\nil}%
  \expandafter\myrndaux\tmpb 000\nil
}%

\myrnd{6.94444pt} (rounds up)

\myrnd{6.4999pt} (rounds down)

\myrnd{6pt} (stet)

\bye


Thank you, this is fine. Maybe I haven't understood this sufficiently, but it does not seem to be exact enough. (6pt vs 6.94pt). Please have a look at my "workaround" answer.

@MBE oh, I just didn't read the question carefully enough and rounded it to the nearest point. if you are reusing this in typesetting, there is not much point in being too precise anyway because dimensions arithmetic is inherently inaccurate in tex. (it is 'good enough' for most purposes, but every step introduces inaccuracies.)

@MBE doubtless a better way to do it, but you just need a couple more steps. see edit.

This uses e-TeX extensions so that the macro is expandable.
It assumes a positive dimension and exploits the fact that \the\dimexpr will always add a decimal part, possibly just .0, after the integral part.
Trailing zeros will be shown and expandability allows to use the macro for an assignment. Since TeX will never show more than five, there's no point in going beyond.
%%%% requires pdftex or xetex or luatex (not Knuth TeX)

\catcode`@=11
\def\therounded#1#2{% #1 = digits, #2 = dimen
  \expanded{\noexpand\therounded@{#1}\the\dimexpr#2\relax}%
}
\expanded{\def\noexpand\therounded@#1#2\detokenize{pt}}{%
  \ifcase#1 
    \expandafter\therounded@zero\or
    \expandafter\therounded@one\or
    \expandafter\therounded@two\or
    \expandafter\therounded@three\or
    \expandafter\therounded@four\else
    \expandafter\therounded@five\fi
    #200000\relax pt
}
\def\therounded@zero  #1.#2#3#4#5#6#7\relax{\therounded@@{}{#1}{#2}}
\def\therounded@one   #1.#2#3#4#5#6#7\relax{\therounded@@{#1.}{#2}{#3}}
\def\therounded@two   #1.#2#3#4#5#6#7\relax{\therounded@@{#1.#2}{#3}{#4}}
\def\therounded@three #1.#2#3#4#5#6#7\relax{\therounded@@{#1.#2#3}{#4}{#5}}
\def\therounded@four  #1.#2#3#4#5#6#7\relax{\therounded@@{#1.#2#3#4}{#5}{#6}}
\def\therounded@five  #1.#2#3#4#5#6#7\relax{#1.#2#3#4#5#6}
\def\therounded@@#1#2#3{#1\the\numexpr#2\ifnum#3>4 +1\fi\relax}
\catcode`@=12

\newlinechar=`^^J

\dimen0=16.90053pt

\message{%
  \the\dimen0^^J%
  0: \therounded{0}{\dimen0}^^J%
  1: \therounded{1}{\dimen0}^^J%
  2: \therounded{2}{\dimen0}^^J%
  3: \therounded{3}{\dimen0}^^J%
  4: \therounded{4}{\dimen0}^^J%
  5: \therounded{5}{\dimen0}^^J%
}

\dimen0=16.94453pt

\message{%
  \the\dimen0^^J%
  0: \therounded{0}{\dimen0}^^J%
  1: \therounded{1}{\dimen0}^^J%
  2: \therounded{2}{\dimen0}^^J%
  3: \therounded{3}{\dimen0}^^J%
  4: \therounded{4}{\dimen0}^^J%
  5: \therounded{5}{\dimen0}^^J%
}

\dimen2=\therounded{0}{\dimen0}
\message{\the\dimen0 \space --> \the\dimen2^^J}

\setbox0=\vtop{abc\par def\par ghi}

\message{Height plus depth: \therounded{2}{\ht0+\dp0}^^J}

\bye

The output on the console:
16.90053pt
0: 17pt
1: 16.9pt
2: 16.90pt
3: 16.901pt
4: 16.9005pt
5: 16.90053pt

16.94453pt
0: 17pt
1: 16.9pt
2: 16.94pt
3: 16.945pt
4: 16.9445pt
5: 16.94453pt
16.94453pt --> 17.0pt
Height plus depth: 32.89pt


Too be continued...
 \newbox\mybox{}
\setbox\mybox=\vtop{``This is the content of the box''} 
\the\ht\mybox\  This is the current height of the box

    \par
    \newdimen\start
    \start=\ht\mybox
    \the\start\ This is the start of the loop\par
    \newdimen\stop
    \stop=6.94000pt %
    \the\stop \ This is the wanted height of the box and stop of the loop
    \loop \ifdim\start>\stop \advance\start by -0.00001pt\repeat\par
    \the\start\ This is the resulting value
    \bye


I don't understand this at all. why such a circuitous way to tell tex to use 6.94pt? I assumed you wanted to typeset the result, without knowing what the result would be. but apparently not?

@cfr
Well, it might be too accurate and too ambitious , but I like to play with those accuracies. In fact, I want to typeset the results too, but they are to wide for the boxes, so I wanted to shorten them. But there is no reason, not to be accurate,

that's not what I mean. what I mean is that you cannot be accurate once you are dealing with tex dimensions. even storing a dimension introduces inaccuracies. e.g. if you store 1pt in a dimension register, you don't necessarily have 1pt stored in the dimension register. you might have 0.999pt or 1.0001pt or something.  if you want to maintain accuracy, store integers and divide only at the last moment.

try e.g. \newdimen\mydimen \mydimen=0.001pt \advance\mydimen by 0.1pt \the\mydimen to get an idea of what I mean.

@MBE I don't understand your code style. Why do you have \par at line 5? The previous line is empty, so it generates implicit \par, why the explicit \par follows? Why the lines 5-14 are indented? Why do you do such absurd loop where the dimen value is decremented by 0.00001pt which is rounded to 1sp? Try this in order to see this absurd coding \newdimen\value \value=0.00001pt \the\value. It prints 0.00002pt. Why you do this loop which must end exactly when \start=\stop? Why didn't you simply write \start=\stop which have absolutely the same effect?

@MBE I thing your way of thinking is a bit strange. May be you want something but present something different here.  Sure, this way of thinking cannot lead to optimal work with TeX. And with tex.stackexchange too.

@wipet The very fine answers showed, that this is not a trivial problem. My own solutions and questions are of a low level of understanding TeX, but, If I wasn't stupid, I wouldn't have to ask. :-)  Codesytyle? I have none. TeX allows to work around .. even  if it hurts.

@MBE Yes, TeX allows to work with obscure codestyle (for example all code is at a single line), but if I want to present my code here and suppose that somebody will read it, then I should observe a certain staff culture. And random indenting lines, redundant \pars, redundant loops doesn't meet it. You asked (in another thread) why there is downvote. Maybe, I explain the reason of it in this comment.

@wipet
Another argument to be added: I cannot describe in every question the background of the question.

Using the answer of Skillmon, you can use the following code to round a new or calculated dimen.
\newdimen\toround
\def\roundit#1#2#3{%
\toround=#3
\round{#1}{\the\toround}%
#2=\the\roundResult%
\relax}%
\newdimen\newsize
\newdimen\basedimen
\basedimen=50.6784pt %or 0.5\hsize etc
\roundit{4}{\newsize}{\basedimen}
\the\newsize

\roundit{3}{\newsize}{\basedimen}
\the\newsize

\roundit{2}{\newsize}{\basedimen}
\the\newsize

\roundit{1}{\newsize}{\basedimen}
\the\newsize

\roundit{0}{\newsize}{\basedimen}
\the\newsize
\bye


this does not seem to be a different answer. it's just code which uses skillman's code. but his answer already gives usage examples, so what does this add?

A better and more general handling.

..and some respect for the useful answer of Skillmon..

This doesn't seem different to earlier a swears other than introducing bug adding space token to the output  and potentially giving errors if the following text is plus for example if 2nd argument is a skip

@David Carlisle Please could you explain? Why should or could the 2nd argument be a skip? The \newsize is just a value, that may be given to every fitting dimen. The wanted dimen is defined after the rounding, so, I do not see the problem you mentioned.  I have tested this with several units (pt, mm, em, sp) they all work. And, what does this mean: "introducing bug adding space token.." ?

\roundit adds a space token to the output from the newline after #3 if #3 is a register not a literal (as it is in all your examples)  (try [\roundit{2}{\newsize}{\basedimen}] [\roundit{2}{\newsize}{10.1234pt}]  first leaves a space.  2nd argument could be a skip if its an existing length eg try setting baselineskip to a rounded value [\roundit{2}{\baselineskip}{\basedimen} minuscule chance of error]
